# ASP.Net AJAX controls, adding via .ashx page

Tags: asp.net, ajax

Okay, this is a continuation of a previous question of mine, but it is distinct enough to be its own question.  Based on user interaction, I'm calling a .ashx handler via a jquery ajax call, and that handler is building some html for me that includes some Telerik controls like a masked textbox (masked for a phone number like "(###) ###-####".

I got around all the hurdles of using Render() to get the html output of a server control even when it doesn't have a "Page" object or a ScriptHandler object.

However, when I show the control to a user, I see the mask in the text of the textbox, but the mask doesn't "work" in the sense that when a user starts typing, it is as if the mask is really just text.

So, my question is, after putting the html code out for a masked textbox, how do I tell whatever javascript is supposed to mask the input to really start masking on that specific control?

I really hope this made sense.  Please tell me if you need any clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Each ASP.NET AJAX control has a $create method to actually setup the AJAX features and to link the HTML elements to the AJAX component.  In the JQuery success callback, you have to call this $create.  For the syntax, look at a masked text box as it would appear normally on the page, meaning look for the following statement for the masked text box:

```
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
   $create(...);
});
```

And copy that definition and use that for your dynamic masked textbox in the callback.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks Brian -- that did help.  I haven't tried it out yet but I saw the code you were talking about, and I've identified the variable parts of it.  You've given me a great pointer in the right direction, and thanks so much.